# How to find the distance between instances within a cluster in WEKA?

Tags: weka, centroid

I have done clustering for a set of text documents using Weka.It grouped similar documents into a cluster.I want to measure how the text documents close to each other within a cluster.How to calculate the distance between the documents within a cluster.

Anyone please help me.I am a new user to Data mining.

Comment: Which clustering algorithm did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for simpleKmeans clustering algorithm:

```
EuclideanDistance Dist = weka.core.EuclideanDistance();
Double distance = Dist.distance(clusterCentroid.instance(clusterNumber), Data.instance(instaceIndex));
```

NB: This distance is normalized